# Pytest hangs on testing database

Tags: pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Pytest to test connection to database which hangs
when I run it:

```
def test_db():
    db.create_all()
    new_comment = Comments(comment='python rocks')
    db.session.add(new_comment)
    db.session.commit()

    entry = Comments.query.all()
    assert len(entry) == 1
    db.drop_all()
```

The table is created successfully but I can't run `select * from Comments;` as it hangs too. I have to kill both windows.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

This code did the trick:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.reflection import Inspector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
   
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@localhost/table')
inspector = Inspector.from_engine(engine)

def test_db():
   db.create_all()
   assert inspector.get_table_names()[0] == 'comments'
   db.drop_all()
```

Comment: So you've basically removed the actual test?